# Is it safe to recompile and replace executable, while a program is in execution?

Tags: operating-system, executable, page-fault

If I run an executable, and during execution, I change the executable by recompilation, is it guaranteed that the program will continue execution as per the old executable? In theory, I understand that page faults can occur and hence, I expect changing an executable during execution,  may not be a great idea. I have searched for an answer, but I have not got a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: Put it this way: most operating systems load the software in memory and that is what is used to run the program.  Where you run into problems is whether your software needs to source something and you've moved or changed a file it needs.  Being that an executable is a package (and thus should all be loaded into memory at once) I would suspect you'd be fine, but this depends on how the program was written and its relationship to the OS.

Comment: It depends whether memory is allocated statically or dynamically... if its allocated statically then changing the executable will not affect the program... as the memory is already allocated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My doubt is more specifically with respect to page faults that can theoretically occur while a process is executing. Since a page fault is caused due to absence of a page in main memory and due to which the page now, needs to be fetched from the hard disk, wouldn't changing the executable cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

1. Many systems will not allow you to do this. Systems that use the executable for paging will lock the file and prevent you from doing this while running.
2. Systems that do allow this, will have loaded everything from the executable into memory or secondary storage. So changing the executable while it is running will not affect the running program.